# Troubles with overloading operator or numbers conversion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I'm learning about overloaded operators in C++, and i've got a problem.

I wrote a (primitive) class to represent a fraction in c++, and a function to multiply two of them.

If I want to multiply fraction by integer using function, everything works very well (thanks to conversion constructor :P). But now i want to multiply fractions by overloaded *, just like two numbers. Multiply `first_fraction * second_fraction` works good, but compilator don't want to convert numbers to fraction in `fraction * 2`. 
(It gaves this error: **error C2666: 'operator *' : 2 overloads have similar conversions)**

If I convert it manually, using `fraction*static_cast<CFraction>(2)` it works again.

Can anyone explain me what am I doing bad? Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CFraction
{

private:
    int m_numerator;
    int m_denominator;

public:

    // Normal constructor, default constructor and conversion constructor
    CFraction(int numerator=0,int denominator = 1) : m_numerator(numerator), m_denominator(denominator)
    {               
    }

    int numerator() const { return m_numerator; }
    void numerator(int numerator) { m_numerator = numerator; }

    int denominator() const { return m_denominator; }
    void denominator(int denominator) { m_denominator = denominator; }

    // Conversion to decimal form
    operator float()
    {
        return m_numerator / static_cast<float>(m_denominator);
    }   

};

// Function to multiply 2 fractions
CFraction multiplication(const CFraction& f1,const CFraction& f2)
{
    return CFraction(f1.numerator()*f2.numerator(),f1.denominator()*f2.denominator());
}

// Overloaded opearator to multiply 2 fractions
CFraction operator *(const CFraction& f1,const CFraction& f2)
{
    return CFraction(f1.numerator()*f2.numerator(),f1.denominator()*f2.denominator());
}

int main()
{
    CFraction fraction1(3,4);

    cout << "Fraction: "<< fraction1.numerator() << "/" << fraction1.denominator() << endl;
    cout << "Decimal: " << static_cast<float>(fraction1) << endl;

    // Multiplication by function works very well
    CFraction result = multiplication(fraction1,2);

    // (ERROR) Compiller won't convert 2 to CFraction class
    CFraction result1 = fraction1*2;

    // Using manually covnerted integer - works again
    CFraction result2 = fraction1*static_cast<CFraction>(2);

    cout << "Multiplied by 2: " << static_cast<float>(result);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

PS. I'm using MS Visual C+++ 2010 if it's matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your class `Fraction` has a constructor which is *not* declared as `explicit` and can accept one argument of type `int`. Therefore, this constructor can be picked by the compiler to realize implicit user-defined conversion sequences every time a `Fraction` is needed, but an `int` is provided.

Moreover, your type `Fraction` also has a conversion operator to `float`, which makes it possible to implicitly convert `Fraction` to `float` every time a `float` is required, but a `Fraction` is provided.

Therefore, the following instruction is ambiguous:

```
CFraction result1 = fraction1*2;
```

The compiler doesn't know whether to pick your overload of `operator *` for objects of type `Fraction` and convert the second argument (`2`) to a `Fraction` by using the constructor of `Fraction` an passing `2` as an input, or rather convert the first argument to a `float` through the conversion operator and then use the built-in `operator *` to perform the multiplication between a `float` and an `int`.

In C++11, you could decide to make the conversion operator `explicit`, and this would prevent the ambiguity: you won't be able anymore to silently get `fraction1` converted to `2`, so the compiler will have only the option to convert `2` into a `Fraction` and invoke your overload of `operator *`.

In this case, if you want to perform the conversion from `Fraction` to `float`, you have to write the cast explicitly:

```
float f = static_cast<float>(result1);
```

The other alternative is to make your constructor `explicit` rather than the conversion operator, so that the compiler won't be able to silently instantiate a `Fraction` when a single value convertible to an integer is provided.

This will solve the ambiguity for the above multiplication itself, in that it leaves the compiler with the only choice of converting `fraction1` into a `float` through your conversion operator. However, two problems will arise.

First, you would not be able anymore to write:

```
CFraction result = multiplication(fraction1, 2);
```

Because this attempts to create a `Fraction` out of the second argument `2` (`multiplication()` expects two `Fractions` as its arguments). Instead, you would have to construct the object explicitly:

```
CFraction result = multiplication(fraction1, CFraction(2));
```

Second, even though your original multiplication above would work, the final copy-initialization of `result1` would not, because (once again) that would require an implicit conversion.

Therefore, you would have to rewrite your copy-initialization as:

```
CFraction result1 = CFraction(fraction1*2);
```

Or as a direct initialization:

```
CFraction result1(fraction1*2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    CFraction result2 = fraction1 * 2;
```

How you use a result has no effect on how it's computed, so this is just:

```
   fraction1 * 2
```

This is ambiguous. You could convert `fraction1` to a float and multiply that by 2. You could convert `2` to a `Fraction` and then use `operator*`. The compiler has no idea which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because you supply a conversion to float in your CFraction class, the compiler has a choice of converting

```
CFraction result1 = fraction1*2;
```

to use either your own operator * with CFractions, or the standard operator * with a float and an int.

If you can use C++11, you could mark your float conversion with explicit. Otherwise, rename it to something like "as_float". Implicit conversions are often problematic and are best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use templates and left conversions to compiler.